# Saving user input in Replit

Tags: c#

## Saving user input in Replit

I am wondering if there is a method of saving user data in replit. I am new to coding and I am making a basic phone book. The language is C Sharp. Here is my Code:

```
while (true) {

//title and options
Console.WriteLine ("Phone book, Please press N to create new contact; S to search for contact:");
 String FO = Console.ReadLine ();

      
//creating new contact  
if (FO == "N") 
   
    Console.WriteLine ("Please input the name of your new contact:");
    String Name = Console.ReadLine ();
    Console.WriteLine ("Please input the phone number");
    String Number = Console.ReadLine ();
      double PhoneNumber = Convert.ToDouble(Number);
      if (PhoneNumber > 10000000000)
        Console.WriteLine("That is not a real phone number. Type");
    Console.Clear();
    String INFO = ("Name: " + Name + "\nPhone number: " + Number);
Console.WriteLine (INFO);
  
     
 //contact access 
    
if (FO == "S") 
     
      Console.WriteLine ("Please input the name of contact you want to access:");
      String accessName = Console.ReadLine ();
      if (accessName == "Name");
      Console.WriteLine (INFO);
    
  break;
  }
```

I have tried looking at the replit forum but i couldn't find anything in C# (They were mainly in python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store the contacts, assuming you mean only as long as the program runs, a way to do this is by using dictionaries, so to have the name as the key and the number as the value.
Here's a good link for learning about dictionaries -> https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-dictionary

For permanent storage, I would use text files. Here's a link for learning a bit about that -> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-read-and-write-a-text-file-in-c-sharp/

Hope this helps

p.s.
I ran this section of code, and it ran after I put it in a Program class and a Main function. There is a few issues with the main body of the program, the first being that the two main if statements lack the curly brackets to group the indented section of lines into the if statement, and so the compiler will only regard the next line as under the if statement, and the rest as not.
Also don't put semi colons after if statements.